# How can I make sure my layout fits to every screen resolution

Tags: css, resolution

see @ http://www.nobleprotocol.com

I am trying to get the sizing of this picture to fit properly to every screen. Any css/html coding tips you can give me to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cover`

```
html { 
  background: url("imageURL") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

source: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/TxyBQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image:url("image.png");
    background-size:cover;
    }
</style>
```